# Using "addImage" or "fillRect", the result is incorrectly placed and/or sized

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm trying to set up a simple "image to PDF" function with jsPDF but I found myself stopped by a strange behavior : the position and size of the picture aren't the one given in parameters.

```
function exportToPdf(src_){
    var pdfSize = [100, 100];

    var pdfDoc = new jsPDF({
        "unit" : "px",
        "format" : pdfSize
    });

    var tempImg = new Image();

    tempImg.onload = function(event_){
        pdfDoc.addImage(
            tempImg,
            "PNG",
            0,
            0,
            pdfSize[0],
            pdfSize[1]
        );

        pdfDoc.save("test.pdf");
    }

    tempImg.src = src_;
}
```

Simple enough : I define the size of the PDF in pixels, load the Image, add it to the PDF at the position [0, 0] and with the size of the PDF and DL it.

[What I expected](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/19/1/1557130992-jspdf-test-0.jpg) versus [the result I have on CodePen](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/19/1/1557130998-jspdf-test-1.jpg)

Seeing this, I tried to tweak the position and, instead of [0, 0], I gave

```
pdfDoc.addImage(
    tempImg,
    "PNG",
    pdfSize[0]/2,
    pdfSize[1]/2,
    pdfSize[0],
    pdfSize[1]
);
```

I expected to have the image start at the middle of the PDF and overflow on the right and bottom sides, with only the top-left quarter visible.

[The result](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/19/1/1557130998-jspdf-test-2.jpg)

---

I have this problem on a basic HTML page, on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bhachet/pen/PvoVVX) BUT the exact same code works perfectly on [the test page of parall.ax](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf).

I feel like there is a scaling issue but I don't understand why. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after more tests, I think I found the answer to my own question :

## The positions and sizes must be given in "pt".

English isn't my native language so I might be wrong but it looks like the [documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html) isn't up to date.

- addImage indicate that x, y, width and height must be "in units declared at inception of PDF document" but there is a clear scaling problem if the unit isn't "pt"
- fillRect doesn't indicate a unit for its x/y but its width/height are asked in pixel. Again, using pixels result in a scaling problem while using "pt" doesn't.